# Jquery Validation Engine not working in Chrome and Safari

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, jquery-validation-engine

I downloaded the Jquery Validation Engine from https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine, it is working perfectly in IE and Firefox but it is not working on Chrome and Safari, the problem is that it does not matter if the fields are empty or invalid characters are entered, the form will always be submitted and since I'm using php to enter the data to a database obvioulsy the fields are entered as empty.

I am sure  I included all needed scripts; have you read about any other member having issues with chrome and Safari using the plug in? I will really appreciate your help Pals.

Adding the code in edit (sorry friends):

```
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/validationEngine.jquery.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/template.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css"/>
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script src="js/languages/jquery.validationEngine-en.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
</script>
<script src="js/jquery.validationEngine.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
</script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        // binds form submission and fields to the validation engine
        jQuery("#collect").validationEngine('attach');
    });
</script>
</head>

<body  onLoad="formReset()" onUnload="formReset()">
<script>
function formReset()
 {
 document.getElementById("collect").reset();
 }
</script>
<div class="formholder">
  <form id="collect" class="formular" method="post" action="insert.php">
<fieldset>
      <label>
    <input value="" data-prompt-position="topRight:0,20"  class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetterSp]] text-input" type="text" name="nombre"  />
  </label>
      <br/>
      <label>
    <input value=""  class="validate[required,custom[email]] text-input" data-prompt-position="topRight:0,20"  type="text" name="email"  />
  </label>
      <br/>
      <label>
    <input value="" data-prompt-position="topRight:0,20"   class="validate[required,custom[phone]] text-input" type="text" name="telefono"  />
  </label>
      <br/>
      <label>
    <select style="height:35px; width:200px;" name="informacion" class="select"  form="contact-form" type= "select">
          <option value="option1">option1</option>
          <option value="option2">option2</option>
          <option value="option3">option3</option>
          <option value="option4">option4</option>
          <option value="option5">option5</option>
        </select>
   </label>
      <input  class="submit" type="submit" value= ""/>
    </fieldset>
    <hr/>
 </form>
   </div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: You should have validation on the PHP side as well, just to be sure. Show your code, we are no clairvoyants.

Comment: Hi Adder, yes I know, it is only that I really like the tooltips with the errors that this plugin displays, I'm still kindda newbie with php stuff as well. I added the code in the form as requested, sorry for that pal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**see this code**

It is working now ...

```
 <!doctype html>
  <html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/validationEngine.jquery.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.validationEngine-en.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.validationEngine.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            // binds form submission and fields to the validation engine
            jQuery("#collect").validationEngine('attach');
    });
</script>
</head>

<body  onLoad="formReset()" onUnload="formReset()">
<script>
function formReset()
 {
 document.getElementById("collect").reset();
 }
</script>
<div class="formholder">
  <form id="collect" class="formular" method="post" action="insert.php">
<fieldset>
      <label>
    <input value="" data-prompt-position="topRight:0,20"  class="validate[required] text-input" type="text" name="nombre"  />
  </label>
      <br/>
      <label>
    <input value=""  class="validate[required] text-input" data-prompt-position="topRight:0,20"  type="text" name="email"  />
  </label>
      <br/>
      <label>
    <input value="" data-prompt-position="topRight:0,20"   class="validate[required] text-input" type="text" name="telefono"  />
  </label>
      <br/>
      <label>
    <select style="height:35px; width:200px;" name="informacion" class="select"  form="contact-form" type= "select">
          <option value="option1">option1</option>
          <option value="option2">option2</option>
          <option value="option3">option3</option>
          <option value="option4">option4</option>
          <option value="option5">option5</option>
        </select>
   </label>
      <input  class="submit" type="submit" value= "test"/>
    </fieldset>
    <hr/>
 </form>
   </div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: What did change? Check the answer as correct, it improves your acceptance ratio.

Comment: Thanks a lot @haseeb, it seems something with the other stylesheets is causing the issue, will check on that and will let you guys know, thanks a lot for you too Adder.

Comment: I found the problem pals, it is related to the display property in my css code :  `.formular input, .formular select, .formular textarea {
 display : block;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 height: 25px;
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.80);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.80);
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.80);
 border-radius: 6px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
 -moz-border-radius: 6px;
}`. Will try to find an alternative to the display:block in my css. Thanks!